# Neo4J Bloom doesn't show properties or categories

Tags: neo4j, cypher

So I load data with python using this code:

```
from neo4j import GraphDatabase

driver = GraphDatabase.driver("connection", auth=("neo4j", "password"))

def add_data(tx):
    tx.run("LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///C:/Users/Damian/PycharmProjects/NeoJ/DataMap.csv' AS Map \
    MERGE (source {node_name: Map.source}) \
    MERGE (destination {node_name: Map.destination}) \
    CREATE (source)-[:FEEDS_INTO]->(destination)")

def add_other(tx):
    tx.run("LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///C:/Users/Damian/PycharmProjects/NeoJ/Data.csv' AS Data \
        Match (node {node_name: Data.dane}) \
        MERGE (system {system_name: Data.system}) \
        MERGE (scope {scope_name: Data.scope}) \
        MERGE (process {process_name: Data.process}) \
        MERGE (owner {owner_name: Data.owner}) \
        MERGE (node)-[:UNDER_SYSTEM]->(system) \
        MERGE (system)-[:UNDER_SCOPE]->(scope) \
        MERGE (node)-[:HAS_PROCESS]->(process) \
        MERGE (owner)-[:IS_OWNER_OF]->(node) ")

def add_data_properties(tx):
    tx.run("LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///C:/Users/Damian/PycharmProjects/NeoJ/Data.csv' AS Data \
    MATCH (n {node_name: Data.dane }) \
    SET n.system = Data.system \
    SET n.scope = Data.scope \
    SET n.process = Data.process \
    SET n.owner = Data.owner")

with driver.session() as session:

    session.write_transaction(add_data)
    session.write_transaction(add_other)
    session.write_transaction(add_data_properties)
driver.close()
```

When I use Neo4J browser everythink is ok. I got nodes with properties and relations. The problem is when I launch it in Neo4J Bloom. I use option to generate perspective and I don't have any properties in nodes, nodes shows only with  and I can only add one category "node" which doesn't show anything.
Example from Browser:
[image: Browser]
Example from Bloom:
[image: Bloom view]

[image: Node category]

Cypher code I use for finding all nodes and connections:

```
Match (n)-[r]->(m)
Return n,r,m
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok nvm. I just changed code to this:

```
def add_data(tx):
    tx.run("LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///C:/Users/Damian/PycharmProjects/NeoJ/DataMap.csv' AS Map \
    MERGE (source:Source {node_name: Map.source}) \
    MERGE (destination:Destination {node_name: Map.destination}) \
    CREATE (source)-[:FEEDS_INTO]->(destination)")

def add_other(tx):
    tx.run("LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///C:/Users/Damian/PycharmProjects/NeoJ/Data.csv' AS Data \
        Match (node {node_name: Data.dane}) \
        MERGE (system:System {system_name: Data.system}) \
        MERGE (scope:Scope {scope_name: Data.scope}) \
        MERGE (process:Process {process_name: Data.process}) \
        MERGE (owner:Owner {owner_name: Data.owner}) \
        MERGE (node)-[:UNDER_SYSTEM]->(system) \
        MERGE (system)-[:UNDER_SCOPE]->(scope) \
        MERGE (node)-[:HAS_PROCESS]->(process) \
        MERGE (owner)-[:IS_OWNER_OF]->(node) ")
```